# SQL - Select all matching ID's if one of the ID's has a certain column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure how to word this question, but it is easier to explain.

If I have a table that looks like this:

```
+-------+----------+-------+
| User  | Result   | Level |
+-------+----------+-------+
|    1  | Victory  |     1 |
|    1  | Victory  |     2 |
|    1  | Victory  |     3 |
|    2  | Victory  |     1 |
|    2  | Defeat   |     2 |
|    3  | Defeat   |     1 |
|    4  | Defeat   |     1 |
|    5  | Defeat   |     1 |
+-------+----------+-------+
```

I want to be able to only select the 'User's that have a victory on level 3.  So the select would return:

```
+-------+----------+-------+
| User  | Result   | Level |
+-------+----------+-------+
|    1  | Victory  |     1 |
|    1  | Victory  |     2 |
|    1  | Victory  |     3 |
+-------+----------+-------+
```

The others would not be returned because they did not complete level 3.

Thanks a lot! I hope I explained it clearly.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to know which users have a victory on level 3:

```
SELECT User FROM my_table WHERE Result = 'Victory' AND Level = 3
```

However, if (as you have shown) you want all of those users' results (with thanks to @Andomar and @ConradFrix for their comments below):

```
SELECT DISTINCT m1.*
FROM   my_table AS m1
  JOIN my_table AS m2 USING (User)
WHERE  m2.Result = 'Victory'
   AND m2.Level  = 3
```

Comment: Would work but returns duplicate rows if a user has more than one victory on level 3, +1 gratz on 10k rep :)

Comment: @ConradFrix: You're too kind.  But given the flaw in my answer as pointed out by Andomar, I do feel it's rather undeserved.  :$

Comment: @eggyal well you could fix the flaw [by adding DISTINCT](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/738ab/3)

Answer (score 3):

You could use an `exists` clause, for example:

```
select  *
from    scores s
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    scores vl3
        where   vl3.user = s.user
                and vl3.Result = 'Victory'
                and vl3.Level >= 3
        )
```

Comment: I think you gain a performance if you do Select * from table where exists(SELECT 1 FROM Table Where X = Y).

Comment: @vaquito: [MySQL ignores the SELECT list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).